# String not being recognized in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a string in a column in a pandas dataframe and change it to another value, but the string is not being recognized. I cannot figure out why.

I imported the dataframe from excel and checked excel and see nothing odd there.
I have tried to copy the text from excel, clear the text in python and type it out directly, and copy and paste from the console - nothing has worked. I have checked for leading or lagging spaces.  I also tried this in a list and used .isin(list) and the same thing happens.

My code is:

```
df.loc[(df['category'] == 'Something - Something Else'),'category']='Changed'
```

I have other values that are being changed here similar to this one, and they update without issue. Any advice on what else I can try?

Comment: There are a few different types of `'-'` characters that could be messing with the equality. You can look at `df['category'].unique()` to see **exactly** what the representation of that string is in your DataFrame, or if you have a ton of unique values, limit to the row (with `.loc[]`)  and see what it is

Comment: Are there leading or trailing white space: `' Something - Something Else'`?

Comment: Thank you ALollz.  I did a unique() on that column in the dataframe and nothing looks off to me.  I also copied the result I received and used that in the code and that is not working unfortunately.  Could it be showing a - when its really not? or one of the other types you mentioned?

Comment: Thank you It_is_Chris.  I don't see anything leading or trailing.  I checked the dataframe as mentioned in the last comment, with the .unique() and then also in Excel and don't see anything there either.

Comment: I have also tried forcing the encoding in the pd.read_excel to utf-8.  Still not working.  I can see that it is not a proper dash but I can't seem to see what it actually is.